# Tried to upgrade DokuWiki farm setup on Arch, wiki is totally hosed now

Tags: php, dokuwiki

I tried to upgrade a DokuWiki install on Arch, and have managed to really hose my install.

I use a farm with domains for my different animals. The core wiki is at http://wiki.hyrule.cc.

With all my plugins enabled, I see this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class DokuWiki_Action_Plugin, because the name is already in use in /var/lib/dokuwiki/plugins/action.php on line 16
```

I added a stacktrace dump right before this class is declared in the indicated file, and it seems like another plugin that takes a dependency on `action.php` is loading first, and it's causing problems. If I disable that plugin (`blog`, in this case), I see a new error that's similar to the above but referencing `syntax.php` instead.

If I nuke my plugins directory and just include the basic php files, I get a different error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'dokuwiki\plugin\config\core\Setting\Setting' not found in /usr/share/webapps/dokuwiki/core/inc/deprecated.php:61
Stack trace:
  #0 /usr/share/webapps/dokuwiki/core/inc/load.php(37): require_once()
  #1 /usr/share/webapps/dokuwiki/core/inc/init.php(200): require_once('/usr/share/weba...')
  #2 /usr/share/webapps/dokuwiki/core/doku.php(36): require_once('/usr/share/weba...')
  #3 {main} thrown in /usr/share/webapps/dokuwiki/core/inc/deprecated.php on line 61
```

Aside from wiping my entire dokuwiki install and starting over, is this recoverable?

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem when upgrading beta 2 to beta 3 manually (overwritting it with the changed files)

however i made a backup of the folder first so luckilly i could revert.

next i tried it with the upgrade plugin and went well!
(also much easier than the manual tar.gz upgrade)

so, if you can put back a backup i would suggest you do that, then install the upgrade plugin and use that to upgrade.

good luck!